# Getting instances from all the regions in amazon

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was trying a java program where I can get the list of instances from all the owned regions in amazon. But I am able to get instances from only the US east region. Can any one help me on this please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you can only get the instances from which region you have specified ,Modify your code so that, it can set REGION and get instance list for all the regions and show it at end.

Comment: This is correct. Using the AWS SDK for Java, while the default endpoint is US East, you can change the endpoint to make calls against the other regions. Using [setEndpoint()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceClient.html#setEndpoint(java.lang.String)), describe all of your instances from EC2, then iterate through each of the regions, appending to your list.